# Redirect to asp page using jQuery on a onClick="window.location.href"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to find the correct syntax for the Jquery link bellow(User reactivated) that redirect to a web page on a on Click.

I feel the syntax is incorrect and

So far I have this and it is incorrect.

```
jQuery("#status_text").html('User reactivated.<a href = "#" 
onclick="window.location.href='deactivationreason.aspx ? +$.param(studentid)> Deactivate</a>'");
```

my full function is as this

```
jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
url: '<%= thisUser.AppendIDToURL("/lms/admin/ajax-reactivatestudent.aspx") %>&rand=' + '<%= 
DateTime.Now.Millisecond.ToString()  %>',
                    data: '<%= studentHash %>',
                    async: true,
                    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                        var response = data || 'no response text';
                        var r = response.split('||');
                        var studentid = r[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

you forgot closing the window.location.href try this

```
    jQuery("#status_text")
    .html('User reactivated.<a href = "#" 
    onclick="window.location.href=\"deactivationreason.aspx ? +$.param(studentid)\"> Deactivate</a>');
```

Just a simple typo.